# Como incluir a lib SDL_image para minha solution no Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, sdl

Eu estou tentando criar um jogo em C++ com SDL2 para Windows Phone 8.1

Eu seguir esse tutorial https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/raw-file/tip/docs/README-winrt.md e um jogo com apenas o projeto SDL2/WinRT (sem extensões do SDL) funciona direitinho.

Mas com isso eu posso apenas fazer algumas coisas pequenas como preencher a tela com uma cor.

Eu tentei incluir a lib SDL_image (baixada de hg.libsdl.org) na solution. Mas todos os modos que eu tento para fazer isso acaba com diversos erros no build. Enfim, inserir tanto SDL_image quanto SDL_mixer no projeto não é tão intuitivo quanto deveria ser.

Como incluir propriamente a SDL_image e outras extensões do SDL na minha solution do Visual Studio? Elas também vem com um arquivo .vcxproj, mas apenas incluir na solution e referência-los não funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Essa versão da IDE teve diversas modificações. As libs postas no site da SDL só possui compatibilidade com verções anteriores do Visual Studio.

Pegue o arquivo mais novo neste link para compilar a SDL com VS 2015.
https://buildbot.libsdl.org/sdl-builds/sdl-visualstudio/